# Using street map and street view side by side in a xaringan slide

Tags: r, xaringan

I came across [this example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple#all) from Google that shows how we can place a street map and a street view in a side-by-side fashion. But I don't know how I can create such a view in a `xaringan` slide.

I tried copying the code under "All" tab, saved the contents as an html file, and later imported that file in the `xaringan` slide. But this approach doesn't seem to work. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

([Cross posted from RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/t/using-street-map-and-street-view-side-by-side-in-a-xaringan-slide/75122))

Comment: Hello @Ashirwad, just a question, do you want to integrate a google map into Xaringan? Does it require a key from googlemaps API?

Comment: @Alexis, I just want to highlight a roadway segment and it's corresponding street view by embedding a google map in xaringan. I am not sure about the API requirement!

Comment: @Alexis, you were right about the API key! I don't know how I overlooked that part. But finally I figured it out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out! Here's what we need to do:

1. Go to [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-simple) to open the *Street View Side-By-Side* example
2. Go to *All* tab and click on the *Copy code sample to clipboard* menu
3. Open any text editor (e.g., notepad++), paste the code sample and save the file with `.html` extension
4. Go to [this link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) and follow the instructions given under *Get the API key* section to get an API key
5. Replace the text YOUR_API_KEY on line 7 of the code sample with the API key obtained from Google through Step 4

```
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize&libraries=&v=weekly"
```

6. In the definition of the `initialize()` function, replace *fenway* with the desired location name and change the associated `lat` & `lng`
7. Add the following code to `xaringan`'s source `Rmd` file to create a slide showing the satellite view and street view in a side-by-side fashion

```r
# Adjust width & height to suit your needs
htmltools::tags$iframe(
  src = "path/to/street-view-side-by-side.html", 
  width = 800, 
  height = 450
)
```